# Why isn't setIcon displaying image on JButton?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I swear I've looked everywhere and have been googling for hours. I have added `actionListeners` to all buttons, and when one is clicked, I want to give it an image with `setIcon( image )` like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button) {

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/" +letter+ ".PNG"));
    button.setIcon(icon );
}
```

1) I know it's retrieving the image because `button.getIcon()` gives me something like `file:/Users/path/to/Images/X.PNG`. I've checked if it's null before and after I've set the icon and it's not null afterward.

2) I've tried other variations of setIcon besides `getClass()...` and `ImageIO.read...` and `BufferedImage`.

3) I don't want to add more code because I'm not even sure what else is relevant. I was hoping for some of your speculations

4) In eclipse, I changed my output folder to `src` (instead of `bin`), and that's where my `Images` folder is.

Comment: Check if object icon is null before setting it. If it is null, then the path to icon is not valid

Comment: It's not null and it's definitely a valid path. Wouldn't button.getIcon() not show anything it it was null or if it was an invalid path?

Comment: Which platform are you running your application on?

Comment: Do you do any validation/refresh of the objects? I cant remember the exact one you'll want but you need to repack/validate the swing objects for it to display the change. Try repaint();

Comment: I didn't need to before when it was working. But `validate()` didn't work. And there's nothing to `repaint()` yet. I'm still trying to figur eout how to repack.

Comment: You probably don't need to repack, I just remember using that at some point when using swing. Try to repaint the button

Comment: repaint() didn't work.

Comment: Try subclassing JButton and overriding paintComponent and inside it display icon

Comment: What does subclass mean? Is this it?     public class SquareButton extends JButton {        And how do I "display icon" in the paint class?

Comment: That's what it is already...a subclass.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AlexSilverman : I hope you will find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same problem, I think. I was using Eclipse, tested my code in JGrasp and it worked. Turns out Eclipse wants the resources in the Project folder, not the SRC or BIN.